# Como hacer un boton para eliminar en PHP que no redirija a otro PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, condiciones

estoy haciendo un proyecto para aprender mas y me trabe en una parte, lo que susede es que quiero un boton eliminar que al tocarlo no me recarge la pagina sino que solo elimine un turno.
Para mostrarles tengo codigo de mi proyecto se los paso aqui:

```
 <?php 
if(!isset($_GET['id'])){
    header('Location: home.php');
}else{
    include('model/conexion.php');
    $id = $_GET['id'];

    $consulta = $con -> prepare("DELETE FROM turnos WHERE ID_TURNO=?;");
    $result = $consulta->execute([$id]);

    if($result == true){
        header('Location: home.php');
    }else{
        echo "Error de Eliminacion";
    }

  }

?>
```

Ese seria la parte del eliminar, y tambien paso lo que elimina:

```
      <div class="row">
                    <div class="card-text col-lg-8 col-md-10 col-10 d-flex flex-row flex-lg-row flex-column align-items-start px-3">
                      <div class="d-flex flex-row pe-lg-3">

                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                          <i title="Tratamiento" class="icon_agrandar fas fa-book-medical"></i>
                          <span class="icon_subir ps-1"> <?php echo $dato->TRATAMIENTO ?></span>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="d-flex flex-row pe-lg-3">

                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                          <i title="Zona" style="color:yellow;" class=" icon_agrandar  fas fa-child"></i>
                          <span class="icon_subir ps-1">&nbsp<?php echo $dato->ZONA ?></span>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="d-flex flex-row pe-lg-3">

                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                          <i title="Equipo" class="icon_agrandar fas fa-microscope"></i>
                          <span class="icon_subir ps-1">&nbsp<?php echo $dato->EQUIPO ?> </span>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                    </div>


                    <div class="col-lg-4  d-flex justify-content-end">
                      <a href="eliminar_turno.php?id=<?php echo $dato->ID_TURNO ?>" class=" btn btn_color btn_eliminar ">
                        <span class="cancelar ">Cancelar</span>
                      </a>
                    </div>

                  </div>
```

Ese codigo llama a un php que se llama "eliminar_turno.php" y obtiene la id y asi borra el turno deseado el tema es que cuando se borra la pagina se actualiza y no quiero que pase eso, si alguien sabe como hacerlo por favor expliqueme, muchas gracias, si necesitan algo mas estoy por aca.

Answer (score 1):

La mejor manera será utilizando AJAX

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Elimnar</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
function realizaProceso(valor){
        var parametros = {
                "id" : valor
        };
        $.ajax({
                data:  parametros, //datos que se envian a traves de ajax
                url:   'eliminar_turno.php', //archivo que recibe la peticion
                type:  'post', //método de envio      
                success:  function (response) { //una vez que el archivo recibe el request lo procesa y lo devuelve
                        $("#resultado").html(response);
                        location.reload();
                }
        });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" href="javascript:;" onclick="realizaProceso(<?php echo $dato->ID_TURNO ?>)" value="Eliminar"/>
<br/>
Resultado: <span id="resultado"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Recibimos los parametros en eliminar_turno.php

```html
<?php 
if(!isset($_POST['id'])){
    header('Location: home.php');
}else{
    include('model/conexion.php');
    $id = $_POST['id'];

    $consulta = $con -> prepare("DELETE FROM turnos WHERE ID_TURNO=?;");
    $result = $consulta->execute([$id]);

    if($result == true){
        echo "Eliminado";
    }else{
        echo "Error de Eliminacion";
    }

  }

?>
```

Comment: solo como detalle, comentar que el isset() solo comprueba la existencia del indice. no su valor. Creo que seria mejor usar en este caso un empty(), asi podrias asegurar que $id tendra un valor. Por otra parte, al ser una función de uso de ajax, seria bueno que la respuesta fuera un json que pudiera interpretar el frontend y que se encargue el de mostrar el error.

Comment: Com ajax no me sirvio no borra el turno, como que no encuentra el id

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que utilices **Fetch** con **Javascript** el cual te permite enviar una peticion **asíncronas utilizando promesas y de forma que el código sea un poco más sencillo y aparte es el nuevo estandar de Javascript según el EcmaScript** y por otro lado, por **SEGURIDAD** utiliza el metodo **POST** ya que por medio del metodo GET estas mostrando el codigo en la URL y cualquiera puede seguir escribiendo peticiones de eliminacion mientras que con POST el hilo va interno y así ejecutas la eliminación del dato sin recargar la pagina y sin exibir algun dato:

Este Seria el llamado a la funcion:

```
<input type="button" href="javascript:;" onclick="eliminarRegistro(<?php echo $dato->ID_TURNO ?>)" value="Eliminar"/>
```

Este seria la funcion:

```
function eliminarRegistro(id_eliminar){

var formData = new FormData();

formData.append('id', id_eliminar);


fetch('./eliminar_turno.php', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: formData
})
.then(response => response.text())
.catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
.then(response => console.log('Exitoso:', response));
}
```

Aqui el php que recibe:

```
 <?php 
if(!isset($_POST['id'])){
    header('Location: home.php');
}else{
    include('model/conexion.php');
    $id = $_POST['id'];

    $consulta = $con -> prepare("DELETE FROM turnos WHERE ID_TURNO=?;");
    $result = $consulta->execute([$id]);

    if($result == true){
        echo "Eliminado";
        return;
    }else{
        echo "Error";
        return;
    }

  }

?>
```

Como veras, en el php cambie que recibes por metodo post ya que es mas seguro y tambien cambie la salida colocandole return.

Espero que te haya podido ayudar.

Comment: duda ese fetch donde cierra?

Comment: y no se que le pasa, cuando toco el boton emm me muestra en consola todo mi codigo jajaja no se que le pasa

Comment: Estimado @FdeFacundo el fecth cierra en ")}" luego le siguen las promesas y la funcion completa se cierra con el ultimo " }", el return ya te lo cambie en la respuesta del php y deje el console para que vieras como manejar la respuesta y tomar las acciones siguientes.

Comment: Por favor, si te funciono alguna respuesta debes ACEPTARLA para que otros se beneficien de tu pregunta y las respuestas aqui planteadas... Gracias!

Comment: emmm @Alberto Marún estoy probando lo que me pusiste y no elimina el turno, osea no hace lo que quiero que haga jejeje

Comment: acceptaria esta respuesta pero no me funciona al borrar el turno, si me eliminara el turno ya estaria y le daria un tremendo like

Comment: @FdeFacundo mi estimado, cuál es el error que te da, porque si es de mi código me gustaría saber para seguir ayudándote, pero si es de base de datos o es parte de tú código se escapa de mis manos porque no tengo tu base de datos y no sé si tu select está correcto.

Comment: no se si estaras por aca pero logre que borrara ahora el tema es que cuando le doy al boton no pasa nada y luego cuando actualizo la pagina ahi si lo borra, me faltaria hacer que borre el turno sin que se actualize la pagina sabras hacer eso?